# How to deploy a justpy project on pythonanywhere or on anywhere else?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, justpy

Does anyone know how to deploy a justpy project on python anywhere or even on other similar providers?
I am new to this, I confused about how to make it run the server after I uploaded the files and how should I install the requirements?

I searched for that but zero results!
I appreciate any help any link any advice.

Comment: justpy would not work on PythonAnywhere as it does not support asgi web apps.

Comment: Thank you Filip, Actually, I am transferring everything to django since I realized the weakness of justpy community, but let me ask you (for knowledge), how can you deploy a justpy project, please if you have an idea?

Comment: According to justpy docs, you need to use Uvicorn.

Comment: I see, I thought there are other ways, thank you so much.